# How do I convert scenario to python code : Have 3 conditions needs to be checked explicitly and mentioned in body

Tags: python

Scenario Ex
If in value column we have 90,95,99,100,102. So basically flag is false only condition where flag(threshold) crosses 100. Else flag should be true. Next tym value is greater than 100 then flag should be true and flag2 should be 0. And only case where we need to consider flag2 values should be 1 is condition 1) value should be less than 100 2) previous value should be less than 100 and 3) flag = F.

Value condition flag

90    T         0

95. T.        0
96. F.        1
97. T.        0
    Value and condition are two input columns we need to compute only flag result based on these 2 attributes value and condition and considering the fact of above mentioned conditions.

Comment: have you checked `if` `else` conditions?

Comment: if value > 100:
    flag = 1
as for the rest i am unsure of what you are asking

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I hope I've understood this time.

Only case where Flag is 1 is:

When value > 100 AND previous value < 100 AND condition == 'F'

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'value':[100,95,96,97,110,120,55,750],'condition':['F','T','T','T','F','T','T','F']})
_condition1 = data.value > 100 
_condition2 = data.value.shift(1) < 100 
_condition3 = data.condition == 'F'
data['flag'] = np.where(_condition1 & _condition2 & _condition3,1,0)
data
```

OUTPUT :

[image]

And now, explanations of what 'shift' does :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'original_values':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]})
df['shift_1_down'] = df.original_values.shift(1)
df['shift_2_down'] = df.original_values.shift(2)
df['shift_1_up'] = df.original_values.shift(-1)
df['shift_2_up'] = df.original_values.shift(-2)
df
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion or debugging sessions; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228342/discussion-on-answer-by-lumber-jack-how-do-i-convert-scenario-to-python-code-h). Please make sure to update the answer with any/all relevant insights.

Comment: Don't forget to mark your answer to end this thread, other community members can benefit from it.